# Scrape Cargo Number Tracking Status with XMLHTTP Request with dynamic content

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have to create several functions that get the status of the supplied cargo number from each different website.

Below is the code user [Zwenn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10046897/zwenn) helped me with. However, I am not familiar with the RegEx and Replace methods of VBA.

I am trying to simplify this code so I can replicate it for other websites. I understand that each website will need a unique code, but if the base stays the same and I can then modify the exact element needed to be scraped would be ideal.

```vb
Function FlightStat_AF(cargoNo As Variant) As String

    Const url = "https://www.afklcargo.com/mycargo/api/shipment/detail/057-"
    Dim elem As Object
    Dim Result As String
    Dim askFor As String
  
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url & cargoNo, False
        .send
        Result = .responseText
    
        If .Status = 200 Then
            If InStr(1, Result, "faultDescription") = 0 Then
                askFor = """metaStatus"""
            Else
                askFor = """faultDescription"""
            End If
      
            With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .Pattern = askFor & ":(.*?),"
                Set elem = .Execute(Result)
            End With
      
            Result = Replace(elem(0).SubMatches(0), Chr(34), "")
        Else
            Result = "No cargoID"
        End If
    End With
  
    FlightStat_AF = Result
End Function
```

I am trying to create a similar function for the below website.

**URL = https://booking.unitedcargo.com/skychain/app?service=page/nwp:Trackshipmt&doc_typ=AWB&awb_pre=016&awb_no=**

**Sample CargoNo = 60848034**

The element to scrape is highlighted in yellow
[image: Element to Scrape]

Comment: Is the location of that `Delivered` status always there in that specific row or it may be anywhere in the table? Could you share another `CargoNo`?

Comment: @SIM, Yes. It will be in that specific row. Basically that is the 1st row. And I want to scrape whatever is in that cell. Some more cargo nos are 10205436, 60848034, 12345678, 60848045

Comment: If you are running this in a loop you are better off modifying the function to pass the xhr and htmldocument variables as arguments rather than repeatedly creating and destroying. Also, if passing as a string then declare as such in the function signature and pass ByVal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should fetch you the required status as long as it is available.

```
Sub PrintStatus()
    MsgBox GetDeliveryStat("60848034")
End Sub

Function GetDeliveryStat(cargoNo As Variant) As String

    Const Url = "https://booking.unitedcargo.com/skychain/app?service=page/nwp:Trackshipmt&doc_typ=AWB&awb_pre=016&awb_no="
    Dim dStatCheck$, deliveryStat$, S$
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url & cargoNo, False
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With
    
    With CreateObject("HTMLFile")
        .write S
        On Error Resume Next
        dStatCheck = .getElementById("trackShiptablerowInner0").getElementsByTagName("b")(0).innerText
        On Error GoTo 0
        If dStatCheck <> "" Then
            deliveryStat = dStatCheck
        Else
           deliveryStat = "Not Found"
        End If
    End With
    
    GetDeliveryStat = deliveryStat
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you @Sim. The code works perfectly. I will try replicating this code for 3 or 4 other websites. But I may need some help in case I am unable to get the code right for any of the websites.